# Is it a Linked list implementation?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am just learning pointers in C and implemented a singly linked list with 3 elements. Is this the right way of approach. Even if it isn't, does the code which I have written represents a linked list?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *link;
};

int main()
{
    struct node first;
    struct node second;
    struct node third;
    first.a=1;
    first.link=&second;
    first.link->a=2;
    first.link->link=&third;
    first.link->link->a=3;
    printf("\n%d",first.a);
    printf("\n%d",second.a);
    printf("\n%d",third.a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have written correctly constructs a singly linked list, but is not a general implementation of a singly linked list data structure. For this, the operations that can be applied to a linked list (for example `insert` an element at a given position, `append` an element to the end of the list or `count` the number of elements in the list) are abstracted out and moved into utility functions.

So, as a next step, try implementing a `void append(struct node* head, int value)` function that, given a pointer to the head of the list, appends a new node with the given value to the end of the list. Then, try to express the construction of your list using this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
 struct node
{
    int a;
    struct node *link;
};  
int main()
{
    struct node first;
    struct node second;
    struct node third;
    first.a=1;
    first.link=&second;
    first.link->a = 2;
    second.link=&third;
    second.link->a=3;
    printf("\n%d",first.a);
    printf("\n%d",second.a);
    printf("\n%d",third.a);
    return 0;
}
```

//the nodes in each struct need to point to the next struct, your code was changing the original destination of first.link from pointing to second and then to third, 
it cannot point to both, second contains pointer to third, third would contain pointer to fourth....